# Can't find type 'ResourceDictionary'?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML as a resource dictionary but Visual Studio 2008 is telling me that it can't find the `ResourceDictionary` tag.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Locate.Client.Views" 
    xmlns:Presentation="clr-namespace:Locate.Client.Presentation;assembly=Locate.Client.Presentation">
```

The specific error message is `Error    1   The type 'ResourceDictionary' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  C:\dev\Locate\src\Locate.Client\Views\..\Resources\MainWindowResourceDictionary.xaml    1   2   Miscellaneous Files`
.

Any reason why it can't find this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks ok to me.

Vs2008 is buggy when it comes to using with XAML. try to upgrade to 2010 if you can. if you still using VS, make sure you got latest SP

otherwise, try to reopen, had similar issue in the past, restart fixed it miraculously :)  upgraded to VS2010 at the end

Comment: Very buggy indeed. I restarted as you did and it fixed the issue momentarily then came back. I deleted my project and checked it out again from SVN. All *appears* to be working correctly. Thank you.

Comment: i know. you are way better off to upgrade to VS2010 if you have a chance and license. makes huge difference. not only for XAML but for all >50 projects in solution